# How do I get Realtime document updates from Firebase Firestore with change.type =="added'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I presently can realtime update modified data with the following code.  What I am trying to accomplish is to listen for new documents added and then realtime update my posts.  I believe it is in line 8 // listen for new docs that is causing the issues.

```
getPosts() {
  this.posts = [];

  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Loading Feed..."
  });

  loading.present();

  let query = firebase.firestore().collection("posts").orderBy("created", "desc").limit(this.pageSize);

  query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    let changedDocs = snapshot.docChanges();

    changedDocs.forEach((change) => {

      if (change.type == "added") {
        console.log("New Message: ", change.doc.data());
        for (let i = 0; i < this.posts.length; i++) {
          // if (this.posts[i].id === change.doc.id) {
          if (change.doc.isEqual(this.posts[i])) {
            this.posts[i] = change.doc;
          }
        }
      }


      if (change.type == "modified") {
        console.log("Modified Message: ", change.doc.data());
        for (let i = 0; i < this.posts.length; i++) {
          if (this.posts[i].id == change.doc.id) {
            this.posts[i] = change.doc;
          }
        }
      }

    })
  })

query.get()
  .then((docs) => {

    docs.forEach((doc) => {
      this.posts.push(doc);
    })

    loading.dismiss();

    this.cursor = this.posts[this.posts.length - 1];

    console.log(this.posts);

  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

Comment: I don't know for sure what the problem is, but I wonder if line 11 is part of the culprit. Using the `==` might not work the way you're expecting since JavaScript will do a referential comparison and not a deep equality check. Is this the behavior you want? Maybe it would be better to use `change.doc.isEqual(this.posts[i])` instead? I got that from the firebase documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  It has the same result.  Shows up in console as a new Message but does not update like Modified Message does.  But once again thank for replying.

Comment: Can you tell me what in general you are trying to accomplish? I don't know what `this.posts` represents, so I don't know what you are trying to get at. I guess from what I see, if you added a new document, why would anything in `this.posts` match the `change.doc`? Wouldn't you just want to push it to the end of `this.posts`?

Comment: What i am trying to get is when a new post is added it shows up in realtime.  I will edit the code to show the whole method.

Comment: this.posts is a collection in firestorm that contains messages sent by users

Comment: So in your `change.type == 'added'` handler, wouldn't you just want to do `this.posts.push(change.doc)`? If it's a new document it wouldn't already be in `this.posts` right? I'm assuming `query.get()` initializes `this.posts` with whatever posts already exist while `query.onSnapshot()` is listening for changes and handles any changes that come in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the problem is that you're checking to see if `this.posts[i]` equals the added doc, and by definition, your doc won't be included in `this.posts`, since it's a new document. There's nothing in the code that's updated `this.posts` with the new data yet.

That said, based on your code, I'm not sure I would even bother looking at docChanges. The point of using docChanges is when you want to do something very specific when a doc changes, like adding a fade-out animation when a document is removed from your data or something. Can you simply blow away your old posts array and set the new array equal to the documents you get back in your snapshot listener?

Comment: I am actually starting over from scratch using AngularFire.  I will post my code for others when I have it built